# ISC DHCP for relay agents

Tags: linux, dhcp, isc-dhcp, dhcpd

I would like to configure DHCP server for my networks, but in the same time, i don't want to setup dhcp server on the network where the server itself is.

DHCPD insist to configure subnet declaration for the network of the ens192 interface (which i really dont want to as there is another DHCP server (on Windows Server)).

```
Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

Is there any way to configure only those networks with realy agents and ignore ens192 network?

Interfaces:

```
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9c:1d:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.144.0.45/24 brd 10.144.0.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;

# MNGT VLAN2 via 10.145.2.1
subnet 10.145.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.145.0.2 10.145.0.253;
        option routers 10.145.2.1;
        option broadcast-address 10.145.0.255;
        option domain-name-servers 10.144.0.45;
}

# VLAN 10 via 10.145.10.1
subnet 10.145.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.145.10.2 10.145.10.253;
        option routers 10.145.10.1;
        option broadcast-address 10.145.10.255;
        option domain-name-servers 10.144.0.45;
}

# VLAN 9 via 10.145.9.1
subnet 10.145.9.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.145.9.2 10.145.9.253;
        option routers 10.145.9.1;
        option broadcast-address 10.145.9.255;
        option domain-name-servers 10.144.0.45;
}

# VLAN 8 via 10.145.8.1
subnet 10.145.8.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.145.8.2 10.145.8.253;
        option routers 10.145.8.1;
        option broadcast-address 10.145.8.255;
        option domain-name-servers 10.144.0.45;
}
```

My distro is Rocky Linux 8.5

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define subnet without any range for the server network and it should work as you want.

```
# DHCP for the server network
subnet 10.144.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
}
```